# Adding an input layer without data requirement in Keras

Tags: keras, lstm

I have a `basemodel` with the sample layers below. Here, I want to save weights of the `basemodel` and then load its weights into the `newmodel`.To load weights from basemodel to newmodel, they need to be in the same architecture and shape sizes as far as I know.
Therefore, I added `additional_input` layer because in my basemodel I have two inputs (temporal and constant) but in newmodel, I need one more input layer.

My question is can I make this `additional_input` layer functionless (it will not require any input data and will not impact the results) while training. For newmodel, I will use this additional_input layer with actual data.

I thought about using a placeholder for it. Or does it make sense if I create a fake dataset with all same values for the training of my basemode?

```
constant_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(X_train[1],3), name="constants")
temporal_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1, 1, 5979, 1), name='temporal')
additional_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(X_train[1],3), name='additional')
lstm_1 = tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(1,5))(temporal_input)
flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(lstm_1)

dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(constant_input)
flat_2 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(dense_1)

dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(additional_input)
flat_3 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(dense_2)

concat_1 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([flat, flat_2, flat_3])
dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5979)(concat_1)   
            
basemodel = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[temporal_input, constant_input, additional_input], outputs=[dense_2])
```